# Handle calendar using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I handle the calendar element with Selenium WebDriver with Java? I want to select the date which is the current date + 5 days. Please suggest to me how I can do this. I saw that the calendar contains a webtable.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming ur date picker calendar is in table format you can use:

```
public void checkDate(){

String currentDate = null;
int counter=0;

WebElement tab = driver.findElement(By.id("tabid"));

List<WebElement> rows= tab.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

for(int i =0;i<=rows.size()-1;i++){



    List<WebElement> columns=rows.get(i).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
    Iterator itr = columns.iterator();


    while(itr.hasNext()){

        WebElement we=(WebElement) itr.next();

        if(we.getText().equals(currentDate)){

            break;

        }

        counter=counter+1;
    }

//element to be clicked is +5 to current date
 if(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("tr:nth-child(i) li:nth-child(counter+5)")).isDisplayed()){
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("tr:nth-child(i) li:nth-child(counter+5)")).click();
 }
}
```

PS. This should serve your purpose but you need to handle the case when your current date is in last column of the table.

Comment: Agreed with your answer but there is another concern if my date is 27 or 28 of month then +5 will not be possible because that date will come in next month ans it will be disable untill we select next month from

Comment: Dropdown mentioned above the calander ..I m still looking for perfect solution

Comment: please post snapshots of calendar

Comment: Why don't you add 5 days in current date at the beginning and then select the date and month accordingly

Comment: @Akash W : nice suggestion, we can check if the resultant date is >30 , 31 or 28/29 for feb and subtract the total from these four situations and select that in next month.

Comment: @Kushal you don't need to write if else loop, just refer below code to get values

Answer (score 1):

First Add 5 days in date. Then extract only integer value of date and integer value of month. Once you have these values you can easily select date.

Use below code

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(new Date()); // Now use today date.
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 5); // Adding 5 days
String output = sdf.format(c.getTime());
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+ 1;
int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
System.out.println("Month : " + month + " day : " + day);
```

Comment: Akash ..I the above code i dont understand where are we comparing the current date . What is current date is 28 and +5 date id 3rd of march is disable ..What should we do in this scenario